# Работа Reverence Type

Tags: javascript

```js
var user = {
  name: "Вася",
  hi: function() { alert(this.name); },
  bye: function() { alert("Пока"); }
};

user.hi(); // Вася (простой вызов работает)

// а теперь вызовем user.hi или user.bye в зависимости от имени
(user.name == "Вася" ? user.hi : user.bye)(); // undefined
```

1. `user.hi()` из точки `Reverence  Type` мы получаем 
   `base - имя объекта` со значением `name - имя свойства` и вызываем в контексте
   `base`.
2. `user.hi` или `user.bye` тут непонятно почему получаем `undefined`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Этот код:

```
(user.name == "Вася" ? user.hi : user.bye)(); // undefined
```

эквивалентен

```
var temp = (user.name == "Вася" ? user.hi : user.bye);
temp();
```

При вызове функции `temp()` - `user` в качестве контекста вызова (то, что будет `this` внутри функции) - потерян. Контекстом вызова становится глoбальный объект `window`.

```js
var user = {
  name: "Вася",
  hi: function() { console.log(this.name); },
  bye: function() { console.log("Пока"); }
};

user.hi(); // Вася (простой вызов работает) - контекст вызова - user

// а теперь вызовем user.hi или user.bye в зависимости от имени
var method = user.hi;
method(); // вот почему: контекст вызова - window

method.call(user); // контекст вызова - user
method.bind(user)(); // контекст вызова - user
```

Comment: вот тут var method = (user.name == "Вася") ? user.hi : user.bye; user.name получаем значение свойства (Вася). Вася == Вася будет true выполнится user.hi. this ключевое слово для доступа к текущему объекту (все дальше заглох)

Comment: тут сказано что Скобки () получают из base значение свойства name и вызывают в контексте base.

Comment: Другие операторы получают из base значение свойства name и используют, а остальные компоненты игнорируют.

Comment: user.hi тут нету () значит контекст нету значит this ключевое слово для доступа к текущему объекту так надо нету кавычек ближайший объект это window; тут нет переменной name значит будет error правильно ?

Comment: тут var method = user.hi; будет var method = function() { console.log(this.name); } теряется объект user  и как тут сказано https://learn.javascript.ru/object-methods#metody-u-obektov        this это ссылка на текущий объект; при потере объекта user текущим объектом будет window правильно ?

Comment: @xes это то, что я написал в ответе

Comment: в объекте используется слово export что он делает ?